# WPF giving slow performance on a particular win 8 machine

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, telerik, rendering

I have a WPF application utilizing Dotnet framework 4.0 client profile.
The application is running perfectly on any windows 8.0 Dell touch screen machine.
I am trying to run the application on a machine having Intel HD Graphics 4600. The application run is very slow and even the transition effect takes longer.

As I have seen somewhere suggested to try Disabling Hardware Acceleration - I din find any registry key named :

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration

I have updated the Graphics Driver and all the windows updates are done.

Can anybody please tell me how can I find / change the Hardware Acceleration / Rendering Mode ?
Or is there anything else that need to be checked ?

Update: I have tried setting RenderOption forcefully to SoftwareOnly and result was still the same.
Some more info about the application:
- Its a multi threaded application - doin some checks in the background.
- We are using some of Telerik controls [Telerik UI fro WPF] and version is 2014.1.00331.40
- System details :
Processor : Intel Core(TM) - i5 -4200M CPU @2.50 GHz
RAM : 8GB
Pen and Touch : Full windows touch pints with 10 touch points

Please suggest anything why its working this much slow for this particular machine.

Comment: I don't know if it relates to the performance; but why are you using client profile? Whats wrong with the full framework?

Comment: Well, I know its naive thing but the project was setup like that. and I have mentioned it here to identify if that could be an issue.

Comment: try to update the Intel GPU driver.

Comment: I have used forceful Softwareonly rendering with luck - do you still think its a Graphic driver issue ?

Comment: In fact windows says that the graphic driver is uptodate